# Access front end SQL back end secure connection

Tags: sql-server, security, microsoft-access

I need to have an Access front end and SQL 2005 back end for a client. I would like to require them to have a static IP and I'll open a port for that IP. But they also want to be mobile, so their IP will change when they aren't in their office.

Is there another way to secure the connection?

Answer (score 3):

Long term solution: Mobile IPv6 on the laptop. The client will then always have the same IP address when connecting to the internal resource.

Short term solution: VPN on the laptop. The client will then have an IP address when within the internal network, and be able to obtain an IP address on the internal network when outside.